# Removing Colons From Multiple FIles on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, bash, copying, renaming

I am trying to take some directories that and transfer them from Linux to Windows. The problem is that the files on Linux have colons in them. And I need to copy these directories (I cannot alter them directly since they are needed as they are the server) over to files with a name that Windows can use. For example, the name of a directory on the server might be:

IAPLTR2b-ERVK-LTR_chr9:113137544-113137860_-

while I need it to be:

IAPLTR2b-ERVK-LTR_chr9-113137544-113137860_-

I have about sixty of these directories and I have collected the names of the files with their absolute paths in a file I call directories.txt. I need to walk through this file changing the colons to hyphens. Thus far, my attempt is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

$DIRECTORIES=`cat directories.txt`
for $i in $DIRECTORIES;
do
    cp -r  "$DIRECTORIES" "`echo $DIRECTORIES | sed 's/:/-/'`"
done
```

However I get the error:

./my_shellscript.sh: line 10: =/bigpartition1/JKim_Test/test_bs_1/129c-test-biq/IAPLTR1_Mm-ERVK-LTR_chr10:104272652-104273004_+.fasta: No such file or directory ./my_shellscript.sh: line 14: `$i': not a valid identifier

Can anyone here help me identify what I am doing wrong and maybe what I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are all these folders present under the same directory or scattered across the file-system? Please tell us more about where all the folders are placed. Example : recursively? Spread across under different directories? Or under same directory?
You may use rename -n 's/://' * if they are all under same directory.

Comment: They are all in the same subdirectory. Thanks so much for your reply. I would like to copy them instead of renaming them, would I just change the mv to cp then?

Comment: Are you okay with changing the folder names in Linux as well and then copy to Windows?

Comment: Yes, that was what I was looking to do actually. There may not be enough room in the same partition (these are some rather large fasta files) so I thought I would copy the folders with the new names to my home directory then transfer them.

Comment: Do not use a `$` when you *assign* a variable: `x=1` not `$x=1`

Answer (score 4):

This monstrosity will rename the directories in situ:

```
find tmp -depth -type d -exec sh -c '[ -d "{}" ] && echo mv "{}" "$(echo "{}" | tr : _)"' \;
```

I use `-depth` so it descends down into the deepest subdirectories first.
The `[ -d "{}" ]` is necessary because as soon as the subdirectory is renamed, its parent directory (as found by find) may no longer exist (having been renamed).

Change "echo mv" to "mv"   if you're satisfied it will do what you want.

Comment: +1. I was not even close to constructing this beauty except the find part.

Comment: Heh, I guess "monstrosity" is in the eye of the beholder!